# Hidden row "unhides" after running macro

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I have a worksheet where row 2 is hidden. A macro pastes into this row. Whenever I run this macro the hidden row reappears.

Is there a way to prevent the row from reappearing?

This is my code an it is still unhiding row 2

Sub Update2029()

```
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim LSearchValue As String

On Error GoTo Err_Execute
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter a serial number to search for.", "Enter value")

'Start search in row 5
LSearchRow = 5

'Start copying data to row 2 in "Master" (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 2

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

    'If value in column A = LSearchValue, copy entire row to "Master"
    If Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue Then

        'Select row in "Master" to copy
        Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste row into "Master" in row 2
        Sheets("Master").Select
        Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial


    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

'Position on cell A3
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A3").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied to 2029."

Exit Sub
```

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."
    Sheets("Master").Rows("2:2").EntireRowHidden = True
    ApplicationScreenUpdating = True

```
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are pasting in that row.

If you do this

```
 Sheet1.Rows(2).Copy Sheet2.Rows(5)
```

Where Row 5 is hidden then it will unhide after pasting. The reason it does this is because the row 5 inherits the properties of Row 2.

If you use paste special then it will not. See this example

```
 Sheet1.Rows(2).Copy
 Sheet2.Rows(5).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

If you want to do PasteAll (Scenario 1) then you will have to hide the row again else go ahead with the 2nd piece of code.

Comment: +1 The only post that explains why does this happen and how to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks this seems like the best answer. Will use paste special code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the row you want to hide is on a sheet called "Sheet1" the following line of code will hide the row:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I shall try when back at work in Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, we cannot tell what is making Row2 display. But if you want to make it not display without actually solving the cause you can do the following:

Insert `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` at the beginning of your macro.

Then at the end of the macro insert this replacing [SheetName] for the actual name of your worksheet:

```
Sheets("[SheetName]").Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = true
```

This way the row will hide again before it updates your screen, and it'll be like it never happened.